# Are all Meeseeks polymaths?

Tags: rick-and-morty, meeseeks

I note that one summons them and ***then*** asks them to do something which I also note they never seem to turn down. I was just watching a clip where the narrator describes them as "simpleminded" but apparently despite their appearance and goofy voices, they are actually superintelligent -- or are they somehow hooked into a central knowledge base?

Comment: *"They're not gods"* ~ Rick